# I am requested to provide ethereneum adress. How do i go about to create this?

Tags: ethereum-classic

Please help me to create an ethereneum address and kindly give examples of addresses for ethereneum.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create an Ethereum address?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7087/how-to-create-an-ethereum-address)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to go to https://www.myetherwallet.com/ and create a wallet there.

Create a new wallet and save the generated wallet. Make sure to save the file otherwise you won't be able to recover it.